# How to call Matlab Function in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, matlab

I want to call Matlab function in WPF. When i call that function in console application it works but when i call that in Windows form or WPF C# then it hangs my .net app and doesn't work. Please Share your experience with me:
Code:

```
private void StartrexeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();
        obj.myfunction();
        MessageBox.Show("Done","Checks");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBOx.Show("Error");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the code in question. It could just be that you are blocking the UI thread; which isn't apparent in Console mode as often.

Comment: Most likely the function is failing and getting stuck. maybe an infinite loop :)

Comment: please share your code so that we may be able to share our experiences

Comment: @DJKRAZE spoken like the code evangelist that you are. :)

Comment: ...I am not even sure what to say. Please sir, may we have some more. Maybe it would be cool to know what myfunction() does. I can guarantee that this code is bombing out the the myfunction if you do not get the messagebox.

Comment: @Clavin Smith: myfunction() is a function in matlab that further call uigetdir() in matlab:I'm confuse that it works in console but doesn't work in WPF and windows form: Thanks